# Q and promises chaining

Tags: node.js, promise, q, chaining

Let say A() returns a resolved promise and go to B().
However, in some conditions, i need B() to finish and not execute the next then() ( I don't want to go in C(). I could use defered.reject() within B() method but it does not seem right.

```
var p = pull(target)
.then(function (data) {
    return A();
})
.then(function (data) {
    return B();
})
.then(function (data) {
    return C();
})
```

Any hint ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your way to do branching with promises is the same as it is without them - by an `if` condition mostly:

```
var p = pull(target)
.then(A).then(B)
.then(function (data) {
    if(data) return C(); // assuming B's resolution value is a boolean
});
```

Answer (score 0):

How about just wrapping it inside same then method?

```
 var p = pull(target)
            .then(function(data) {
                return A();
            })
            .then(function(data) {
                var result = B();
                if (!result)
                    return C()
                return result;
            })
```

Comment: B returns a promise, not a boolean.